# How to build multi dex into apk by maven?

Tags: java, android, maven, dex

Our App will exceed 65k methods, so we need to build multi dex into apk according to this guide:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

It use gradle to build apk, but our build system uses maven.
I used this demo to build the apk, but failed.
https://github.com/lsuski/maven-multidex-sample

So how to build multi dex by maven? Anyone has related tutorials or documents? I googled all the internet but find no solution.

**[Update]**
Finally I still can not build multi dex apk by android studio with maven. But I built it succesfully by maven command line.

All of what I did is following:
Modify MyApplication.java, add the method:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Modify the pom.xml, add the following tags:

```
< multi-dex >true< /multi-dex >
< minimal-main-dex >true< /minimal-main-dex >
< dex-arguments >--set-max-idx-number=65536< /dex-arguments >
```

If you can not build by AS, try maven command line.